# Remove and add a row with a server side control to a table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a row which has a server side control. Depending on a condition I need to remove the row completely, so that the HTML cannot be read by screen-readers and re-added later when the condition is changed.

here is the code i am trying but it is not working

my original ASPX

```
    table id="tblmain" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div id="studysub_animal" runat="server">
                    <h3>
                     Select the vALUE.</h3>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rdb_one" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Humans">Humans</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Non-Human primates">Non-Human primates</asp:ListItem>                            
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr_optional">
            <td>

                    <h3> Select your second value</h3>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdb_two" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Individuals</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Population</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the jquery i am writing

```
     $('#<%=rdb_one.ClientID%> input:radio').click(function () {

                var currentIdone = 'Humans';
                var currentId = $(this).val();
                var row = $('#tr_optional');
                if (currentId == currentIdone) {
                    if ($('#tr_studypopul').length) {

                    }
                    else {

                        $('#tblstudysub_animal').append(row);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    $('#tr_studypopul').detach();

                }

            });
```

any idea. how can i add and remove the row conditioanlly.
When the page first loads it loads the row it is only hidden or visible depending on the answer

Comment: You can't create server-side controls in client-side code.  You can create the same HTML markup those controls would have created, but the server-side code isn't going to recognize them as controls containing values.  You'd instead have to use something like `Request.Form` to read those values.

Answer (score 1):

Like David said, you cannot add server-side controls dynamically. However, since it will be shown later on based on conditions, why not just hide it? Try use javascript document.getElementsById().style.display = 'none'. And when you show it, change "none" to "block". It worked for me.